# why does $1 in yacc/bison has a value of 0

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a following production in a `bison` spec:

```
op : '+' { printf("%d %d %c\n", $1, '+', '+'); }
```

When I input a `+` I get the following output:

```
0 43 +
```

Can someone explain why `$1` has a value of 0, shouldn't it be 43? What am I missing?

**EDIT**

There is no flex file, but I can provide a `bison` grammar:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror();

%}

%token NUMBER

%%

lexp : NUMBER 
     | '(' op lexp-seq ')'
     ;
op : '+' { printf("%d %d %c\n", $1, '+', '+'); }
   | '-' { printf("%d %d %c\n", $1, '-', '-'); }
   | '*' { printf("%d %d %c\n", $1, '*', '*'); }
   ;

lexp-seq : lexp-seq lexp
         | lexp
         ;

%%

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (2 == argc && (0 == strcmp("-g", argv[1])))
    yydebug = 1;

  return yyparse();
}

int yylex() {
  int c;

  /* eliminate blanks*/
  while((c = getchar()) == ' ');

  if (isdigit(c)) {
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    scanf("%d", &yylval);
    return (NUMBER);
  }

  /* makes the parse stop */
  if (c == '\n') return 0;

  return (c);
}

int yyerror(char * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
  return 0;
} /* allows for printing of an error message */
```

Comment: You need to show us the flex file, as it is this code that is returning the value to bison.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I've just made an edit. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` is the semantic value of the first symbol on the right-hand side, which in this case is `'+'`. Since that is a terminal, its semantic value will be whatever the value of `yylval` was when the scanner returned a `'+'` token to the parser.

Since your scanner does not set `yylval` in the case that it returns `'+'` (which is totally normal), the use of `$1` in that production is not well defined. Normally, a grammar doesn't reference the semantic values of tokens like `'+'`, which are purely syntactic and don't have semantic values.

However, since `yylval` is a static variable, it will have been initialized to 0, so it will continue to have that value until it is set (for example, while scanning a `NUMBER`).